# PHP Warning: mysqli_error(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in

Tags: mysql, php, query

I am new at this, so this is my case.

I am getting this error on my *Wordpress* site and I need someone to point me out where to search the problem. I know that is written in a log file and here it is, but I need just a recommendation where to search next.

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log

[Wed Nov 06 17:37:34.338255 2019] [:error] [pid 7783] [client 192.168.0.167:55833] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/example.com/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2007, referer: https://example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_status=publish&post_type=post&lang=sq  
[Wed Nov 06 17:37:34.338540 2019] [:error] [pid 7783] [client 192.168.0.167:55833] PHP Warning:  mysqli_errno(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/examle.com/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1902, referer: https://example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_status=publish&post_type=post&lang=sq  
[Wed Nov 06 17:37:34.338756 2019] [:error] [pid 7783] [client 192.168.0.167:55833] PHP Warning:  mysqli_error(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/example.com/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1929, referer: https://example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_status=publish&post_type=post&lang=sq  
[Wed Nov 06 17:37:34.339084 2019] [:error] [pid 7783] [client 192.168.0.167:55833] PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_escape_string(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/example.com/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1172, referer: https://example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_status=publish&post_type=post&lang=sq  
[Wed Nov 06 17:37:34.339421 2019] [:error] [pid 7783] [client 192.168.0.167:55833] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/example.com/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2007, referer: https://example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_status=publish&post_type=post&lang=sq  
[Wed Nov 06 17:37:34.339751 2019] [:error] [pid 7783] [client 192.168.0.167:55833] PHP Warning:  mysqli_errno(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/example.com/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1902, referer: https://example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_status=publish&post_type=post&lang=sq  
[Wed Nov 06 17:37:34.340001 2019] [:error] [pid 7783] [client 192.168.0.167:55833] PHP Warning:  mysqli_error(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/example.com/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1929, referer: https://example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_status=publish&post_type=post&lang=sq
```

Comment: Can you please run a `vim +2007 /home/mia/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php` Operating System Command and tell us how that Source Line of Code is looking like?

Comment: $this->result = mysqli_query( $this->dbh, $query );

Comment: Something is wrong with the _MySQL_ DataBase Setup. These are just _PHP Warnings_. Try to find some messages of higher level. Also, can you try to let us know what is the value of the `$query` PHP Variable on this first PHP Warning?

Comment: line 2007  $this->result = mysqli_query( $this->dbh, $query );
line 1559  while ( mysqli_more_results( $this->dbh ) ) {
line 1902  $mysql_errno = mysqli_errno( $this->dbh );
line 1550  mysqli_free_result( $this->result );
line 1929  $this->last_error = mysqli_error( $this->dbh ); here is the line from wp-db.php and also the error lines from my log

Comment: Something is wrong with the _MySQL_ Instance. Have you tried rebooting the machine? Try to get the DataBase up again somehow.

Comment: No, I haven`t rebooted but I have restarted the MySQL and Apache server but still getting the same errors and cannot find anything suspicious  in MySQL error log

Comment: People are usually using the _Google_ Search-Engine in order to find things out. If you are searching for the "`Couldn't fetch mysqli in`" Character String, for instance, you get to [this _Stack Overflow_ question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937880/mysqliquery-couldnt-fetch-mysqli/26147425) where one of the clues is the fact that "_probably you are trying to execute queries after the closing of the connection using the_ `DBconnection->close();` _call has happened_".

Comment: Thanks but I was asking if someone can point me out strictly about this lines cuz it`s a live server (WordPress) website and I`m a little bit afraid to change the code lines or try but as you suggest best-case scenario would be to clone and test it there, Thanks again guys.

Comment: Check if your DB don't have a dash or underscore in the name